# MySQl Error #1064 42000

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting an error when creating the "orders" table. Any ideas? "customer" table already exists, as does the `cust#` column. Thanks in advance.

```
create table orders(
`order#` char(4) not null,
orderdate date not null,
`cust#` char(4) not null,
amount decimal(10,2) not null,
primary key (`order#`),
foreign key (`cust#`) references customer (`cust#`)
on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine=InnoDB;
```

EDIT: simply a typo. thanks for your responses.

Comment: Why would you use `#` in a column name? You need to post the structure for table `customer`.

Comment: column names are specified by the customer. after questioning this, i lost the naming battle.

Comment: Are you sure that what you posted here correspond with what you have?From that error it sounds your table name is order,which is a reserved name.

Comment: you're right. it was a typo, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Table `customer` must exist before trying to create table `orders`.

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a66c).

While characters such as `#` are permitted, they should be avoided in naming objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `CONSTRAINT` for the foreign key.

```
create table orders(
`order#` char(4) not null,
orderdate date not null,
`cust#` char(4) not null,
ord_amt decimal(10,2) not null,
primary key (`order#`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_cust` foreign key (`cust#`) references customer (`cust#`)
on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine=InnoDB;
```